# how to insert spaces in between elements of an array which is read as an input from the html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

This is the HTML and Javascript code to create a dynamic html table which accepts inputs,

HTML:

```
    <table id="contentTable" border="1" name="contentTable">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
   </table></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
      function buildTable(val)
  {
var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
var j=val;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];

  while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
    myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
}


for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
{
    rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
    if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("every3rdrow");
    cells[i] = [];

    for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
    {
        cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
        cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t onchange=ty() name=t[]>":"<input id=t1 onchange=ty1() name=t1[]>";
        rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
    }
}

     }
       buildTable();    

 function ty(){
   $ad = document.getElementById("t").value;
   if(!/^-?\d*$/.test($ad)) {
       alert("Number of heads per model value must be numeric!");
   } 
       } 

  function ty1(){
   $ad = document.getElementById("t1").value;
   if(!/^-?\d*$/.test($ad)) {
       alert("Number of heads per model value must be numeric!");
   } 
       }
```

This is the php code to extract/read the contents of the html form into a text file,
PHP:

```
     file_put_contents($file, "\n Models Vector:", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['t'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $_POST['t1'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

i have no problem with extracting or displaying the content, but i am not able to give spaces in between elements of the array,
for example:
if i give inputs as 21, 22 and 23, i am getting output as Models Vector: 212223
but i want to give spaces or commas between the elements of the array, like 21 22 23,

now i will tell what i have tried, i gave $_POST['t']."\t" in place of $_POST['t'], but i am getting the output as Models Vector: Array 2223, and if give $_POST['t1']."\t" also i am getting output as
Models Vector: Array Array, why is this happening and how to insert spaces between these array elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the array on your own. As you are writing the array directly to the file, you are getting it displayed however PHP chooses.

A quick solution might be to use `implode(", ", $_POST['t'])` instead of just `$_POST['t']` directly.

Comment: i used 'implode(",", $_POST['t'])' and 'implode(",", $_POST['t1'])', but i am getting the output as Models Vector: 2122,23   there is no comma between 21 and 22, can you resolve this ?

Comment: Is 21 from t and 22,23 from t1? If so you need to write a comma between them or merge the arrays before writing.

Comment: yes,t and t1 are different, i have written a comma between them, thanks for the solution.